# Spark not providing the updated results as available in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hdp

I am using a pyspark code to process some data which is fetched from Hive View. We are currently using HDP 3.1 Version. The issue is i can see that Hive View contains data, for example: Data for date 5th June 2019, where as when i try to fetch the data from Spark SQL, I get the data latest of date 4th June 2019.

I have tried selecting complete data in spark and then ordering it by Date DESC just to be sure about the issue. I have also checked that the data for 5th June is available in Hive.

I came to know that spark and Hive manages different catalog in HDP 3+. But as per my knowledge, Admin has already taken care of pointing Spark to Hive Catalog. Is it the catalog issue, that i need to check again?

**Update:**
Ask asked in comment , here is the sample code i ran in Hive and spark with sample results i got -

**Hive Query**

```
select number,v_date, location, region  from View1 where Upper(category) ="I" and lower(region) ="cochin" and to_date(visit_date) between "2019-06-02" AND "2019-06-06"  order by  to_date(visit_date) desc limit 500;
```

**Sample Result:**

[image]

As shown above, I get results for 5th June in Hive. Now when i execute the same in **PySpark:**

```
data_for_region = sparkSession.sql('select number, v_date, location, region  from View1 where Upper(category) ="I" and lower(region) ="cochin" and date_format(visit_date,"yyyy-MM-dd") between "2019-06-02" AND "2019-06-06" order by visit_date desc limit 50')
```

**Sample Result**

[image]

As you can see, Its just not showing me the results for 5th June , but giving the data from 4th June. I am just not aware of how to resolve this discrepancy.

Comment: Spark uses Hive's metadata to get the DB/tables details. Perhaps you can share some code/detail of what you're doing in a fashion that it's more viewable to us to figure out the issue.

Comment: @knowone, I have updated the question and attached the code to get results (sample). Any pointers about whats happening here?